# Escaping "/" doesn't work in IE9

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, escaping, uri, internet-explorer-9

I have a javascript function that builds an URI fragment using some captured parameters, and then submits my form.

Example:

```
function consultResource(contextName){
    var form = document.forms[0];
    var f1 = form.thename.value;//accepts strings without special symbols
    var f2 = escape(form.thedate.value); //accepts only strings in the form 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    var action = "/"+contextName+"/CtrlComparison?name="+f1+"&date="+f2;
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
}
```

An example generated URI fragment would be
`/MyContext/CtrlComparison?name=report01&date=06/05/2011`

This snippet works, submitting the form and bringing a PDF document OK for:

- Firefox 3.x-4.x (not tested on 2.x)
- Internet Explorer 6-8
- Google Chrome 9.x-11.x (other versions not tested)
- Opera 10.x-11.x (other versions not tested)

But I need it to work in Internet Explorer 9 too. Currently when I submit the same info in IE9 I get the following message:
[image: real result]

instead of something like this:
[image: expected result]

IE9 is not escaping the `/` and taking them as part of path separators on URI.

The question is: **How could I get my URI fragment to be correctly generated in IE9 too?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are the HTTP headers being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem with your form, or action URL.  You need to send the correct headers when you write out the PDF.

In your php
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename:comparativoCajasRegistradas.pdf");

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape` for the query parameter values.

> The encodeURIComponent() function
>   encodes a URI component.
>
> This function encodes special
>   characters. In addition, it encodes
>   the following characters: , / ? : @ &
>   = + $ #

Comment: +1: escape is deprecated, but i don't think that's the real problem. I think James hit the right point, specifying the filename to be downloaded.

Comment: @nihcap: However, you should still use `encodeURIComponent()`

Answer (score 0):

Escape function encodes special characters, with the exception of: * @ - _ + . /.
So replace it on client-side then put it back on server-side.

**JS**

```
var f2 = form.thedate.value.replace(/\//g, "x");
```

**JAVA**

```
f2 = f2.replaceAll("x", "/");
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I edited your answer to replace *all* occurrences of `/` in date reather than only the first. Also, I'm using Java, so server-side code would be `f2=f2.replaceAll("x", "/");`. Albeit, this doesn't work for me.

Comment: This is kind of naive, what if you have x in the string? Just encode using `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Yes, there is. Try encodeURIComponent()... it differs from both encodeURI() and escape().